# How to search multiple strings match in a webpage using python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, webrequest

I wanted to improve the snippet below by passing in multiple strings to search ("English Subtitles", "1080", "2021") in the webpage. Currently, it works with single string search.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.allyoulike.com/'
r = requests.get(url)

singlesearchstring = "2021"

multiplesearchstring = "English Subtitles", "4080", "2021"

if (stringtosearch) in r.text:
    print ('Found ',singlesearchstring )
else:
    print ('Not Found ', singlesearchstring)
```

Wanted Output:

```
Search Results:
  English Subtitles - Found
  4080 - Not Found
  2021 - Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```py
[(q, 'Found' if q.lower() in r.text.lower() else 'Not Found') for q in queries]
```

```py
import requests

queries = ["English Subtitles", "4080", "2021"]


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    for q in queries:
        q = q.lower()
        if q in r.text.lower():
            print(q, 'Found')
        else:
            print(q, 'Not Found')


main('http://www.allyoulike.com/')
```

Updated Answer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from pprint import pp

queries = ["English Subtitles", "4080", "2021"]


def get_line(q, soup):
    return [x for x in soup.findAll(text=re.compile('{!s}'.format(q)))]


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [(q, 'Found', get_line(q, soup)) if q.lower()
            in r.text.lower() else (q, 'Not Found') for q in queries]

    pp(goal)


main('http://www.allyoulike.com/')
```

Comment: is it possible to just return the whole line where the string is found?

Comment: @rbutrnz check updated answer, and take a look on [ask]